# How to convert HTML to image in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, image, phantomjs, image-generation

I need to convert an HTML template into an image, on a Node server.
The server will receive the HTML as a string. I tried PhantomJS (using a library called Webshot), but it doesn't work well with flex box and modern CSS. I tried to use Chrome headless-browser but it doesn't seem to have an API for parsing html, only URL.

What is the currently best way to convert a piece of HTML into image?

Is there a way to use headless Chrome in a template mode instead of URL mode? I mean, instead of doing something like

```
chrome.goTo('http://test.com')
```

I need something like:

```
chrome.evaluate('<div>hello world</div>');
```

Another option, suggested here in the comments to this post, is to
save the template in a file on the server and then serve it locally and do something like:

```
chrome.goTo('http://localhost/saved_template');
```

But this option sounds a bit awkward. Is there any other, more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a library called [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).
Sample code snippet :

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.setViewport({
     width: 960,
     height: 760,
     deviceScaleFactor: 1,
 });            
 await page.setContent(imgHTML);
 await page.screenshot({path: example.png});
 await browser.close();
```

This will save a screenshot of the HTML in the root directory.

Comment: This one is excellent and well maintained and has support for latest web standards!

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do it on frontend using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). On backend you can write the html on a file and access using a [file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) (i.e: `file:///home/user/path/to/your/file.html`), it should work fine with chrome headless-browser and [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) (screenshot feature). Another option is to setup a simple HTTP server and access the url.

Comment: yea I thought about the option of using http server but it seems a bit strange...if no one will suggest a simpler solution ill accept yours because im starting to think there is no simpler solution, tnx

Comment: you can just  write the html file and use a [file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) instead (i.e: `file:///home/user/path/to/your/file.html`), it should work fine with chrome headless:

Comment: oh right, i didn't thought about the file uri thing. sounds good, thanks!

Comment: If you're already using headless chrome, why don't you simply take screenshots fron it?