# How to take a screenshot of a web page and display it using PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, image

I am developing a website, actually in HTML, CSS, and Vanilla JavaScript.

On the site, I would like to display image captures of the current state of my others online creations.

I guess I'll have to use a server-side language to do it,
So how to do it with JS using **Nodejs** or with **PHP** or is there another alternative?.

I would like to do something like this:
[**Sites overview in Netlify**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hj2e.png)

Comment: [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) is probably your best bet, if you're using NodeJS. With it, you can open your page in a headless Chrome browser, and take a screenshot _(that is exactly what the first example code snippet does, in their docs)_

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768888/how-to-convert-html-to-image-in-node-js

Comment: @blex thanks, your solution is very helpful for integration with nodejs

Comment: You're right @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, there is probably a nodejs duplicate, but otherwise, I am also waiting for a PHP solution